# SQL Table Design for Identical Tables/Classes

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, data-modeling

In my code I differentiate between 5 Types of Attributes which 'describe' a project by creating 5 classes inherting from one base Class 'ProjectAttribute'. A Project can have 0 to x (so in SQL many-to-many) of each type of Attribute.
Here some pseudo-code:

```
public abstract class ProjectAttribute
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
}
public class Attribute_HW : ProjectAttribute
{
    public static List<Attribute_HW> Hardware_Attributes { get; private set; }
    static Attribute_HW() 
    {
        // Read Attributes from external DataSource to List 'Hardware_Attributes'
    }

    // Some Attribute specific logic but no more fields
}
// Followed by 4 more Attribute Classes

public class Project
{
    public ICollection<Attribute_HW> AttributesHardware { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Attribute_SW> AttributesSoftware { get; set; }
    // 3 more Attribute Collections
}
```

Each of this classes have a different Set of Data which I want to store in my SQL Database. But it kindy feels wrong to create 5 tables for such identical classes which will result in another 5 Link Tables to link it to another table (many-to-many). Finally I came up with 2 different ideas

**Idea 1**
I create 5 tables and also 5 Link Tables to link it to the 'project' table.
This feels wrong because each Attribute table will contain about 20-30 Entries and I have to query 5 different Link tables to resolve this 'mess'.

**Idea 2**
I create 1 Table named 'ProjectAttrbiutes' and add one additional column for each Attribute Type. I.e. 'IsSWAttribute', 'IsHardwareAttrobite'. In addition I add only one Link Table.
Sounds better but is it advisable to reduce the original data structure back into one table?
On the other hand I would end up with just one Link table to query.

I hope you can point me in the right direction.

Comment: Looks like an XY problem. Without some sampling on what your data looks like I don't think you would get a good answer.

Comment: Uhm, There is currently just the code I sampled above. That is what I try to transfer into an sql database. For simplicity I did not write down all 5 Attribute-Classes and left some fields to make things more clear.

Comment: For a given `AttributesHardware` in example, can it belong to many differents projects?

Comment: I meant what do they look like. Blindly, I would create a single table and a link table where 1st table has ID, Title and Type for the attribute.

Comment: Yes exactly. AttributeHardware along with the 4 other Attributes can be used in many different projects, but a project can have many of each of the Attributes.

Comment: and you tagged the question with mysql, sql, sql_server but not say postgreSQL which has no-sql capabilities within. This might fit to no-sql better.

Comment: For a single project, can it have many **differents** `AttributesHardware` in example ?

Comment: I got my answer, I noticed that `ICollection<Attribute_HW> AttributesHardware`

Comment: MySQL and ms sql server are two different products with different features, therefore I removed the conflicting product tags. Pls add the one back that you use.

Comment: Sorry, ... didn't noticed the wrong tag. It should be correct now!

Comment: You are kinda manually doing and figuring out inheritance.  You can learn alot (and keep in sync) the main methods for this from ORM subclassing.  Again, I'm not saying "do ORM" necessarily, I'm saying "learn from ORM strategies".  Example : https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/inheritance.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would be using 4 tables for that purpose.

A table containing the projects.

A table containing the attributes.

A table containing the attributes types.

A table that links project and attributes

> [Project] -> [ProjectAttribute] <- [Attribute] -> [attributeType]

For the attributes types, there's nice types for that purpose in MySQL and PgSQL, the enum type. In MS SQL you can build a regular table.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/9f329/2)

**MS SQL Server 2017 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE project
(
  id INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
  name VARCHAR(255)
);

CREATE TABLE attributeType
(
  id INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
  name VARCHAR(255)
);

CREATE TABLE attribute
(
  id INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
  title VARCHAR(255),
  type_id INT,
  CONSTRAINT FK_attributeType FOREIGN KEY (type_id)
    REFERENCES attributeType(id)
);

CREATE TABLE ProjectAttribute
(
  project_id INT NOT NULL,
  attribute_id INT NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT FK_project FOREIGN KEY (project_id)
    REFERENCES project(id),
  CONSTRAINT FK_attribute FOREIGN KEY (attribute_id)
    REFERENCES attribute(id),
  CONSTRAINT pk_ProjectAttribute PRIMARY KEY (project_id, attribute_id)
);

INSERT INTO project (name) VALUES ('project 1 with hardware and software');
INSERT INTO project (name) VALUES ('project 2 with hardware only');
INSERT INTO project (name) VALUES ('project 3 with software only');

INSERT INTO attributeType (name) VALUES ('Hardware');
INSERT INTO attributeType (name) VALUES ('Software');

INSERT INTO attribute (title, type_id) VALUES ('Some hardware 1', 1);
INSERT INTO attribute (title, type_id) VALUES ('Some hardware 2', 1);
INSERT INTO attribute (title, type_id) VALUES ('Some software 1', 2);
INSERT INTO attribute (title, type_id) VALUES ('Some software 2', 2);
INSERT INTO attribute (title, type_id) VALUES ('Some hardware 3', 1);

INSERT INTO ProjectAttribute VALUES (1, 1);
INSERT INTO ProjectAttribute VALUES (1, 2);
INSERT INTO ProjectAttribute VALUES (1, 3);
INSERT INTO ProjectAttribute VALUES (1, 4);
INSERT INTO ProjectAttribute VALUES (2, 1);
INSERT INTO ProjectAttribute VALUES (2, 5);
INSERT INTO ProjectAttribute VALUES (3, 3);
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT * FROM project p
INNER JOIN ProjectAttribute pa
  ON p.id = pa.project_id
INNER JOIN attribute a
  ON a.id = pa.attribute_id
INNER JOIN attributeType t
  ON t.id = a.type_id
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/9f329/2/0)**:

```
| id |                                 name | project_id | attribute_id | id |           title | type_id | id |     name |
|----|--------------------------------------|------------|--------------|----|-----------------|---------|----|----------|
|  1 | project 1 with hardware and software |          1 |            1 |  1 | Some hardware 1 |       1 |  1 | Hardware |
|  1 | project 1 with hardware and software |          1 |            2 |  2 | Some hardware 2 |       1 |  1 | Hardware |
|  1 | project 1 with hardware and software |          1 |            3 |  3 | Some software 1 |       2 |  2 | Software |
|  1 | project 1 with hardware and software |          1 |            4 |  4 | Some software 2 |       2 |  2 | Software |
|  2 |         project 2 with hardware only |          2 |            1 |  1 | Some hardware 1 |       1 |  1 | Hardware |
|  2 |         project 2 with hardware only |          2 |            5 |  5 | Some hardware 3 |       1 |  1 | Hardware |
|  3 |         project 3 with software only |          3 |            3 |  3 | Some software 1 |       2 |  2 | Software |
```

Comment: Even so if my Attribute Classes are generally the same? I mean, you displayed them with attribute2 - Data and Data2 (I know I could cancel that out) but in my case the 'Attribute-Classes' are derived from ProjectAttribute and they do not have any Property/Field on theire own except the inherited one. Please confirm or specify. If it still fits in my Situation, I will accept this as answer.

Comment: Considering the relation bewteen common attribute and specific attribute is **One-To-One**, if there's only 2 fields (id and title) in the common one, you don't necessary need to create a new table. But if there's many common fields, this can be nice to add, indeed, a new table. This is just a foreign key to add

Comment: I used this structure in a project, to manage users. There was customers and staff user. Both had in common the fact they have a username, a mail, a password, etc... but staff had a field for the service they work in (and others fields) and customers had a field for the company they're working

Comment: Doesn't that case differ from mine? I mean, I have Attribute_HW and Attribute_SW (and the 3 other Attributes) which all only have ID and Title. No futher properties will be added. In your case I'm fully with you but isn't my case a bit different? Sorry for questioning your answer but I just want to be sure that it's really meant to fit for my question.

Comment: I didn't understood well your question then. I'm editing completly my answer.

Comment: A unique `ProjectAttribute` can be at the same time `hardware` and `software` ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is my one table suggestion (Type is an enum like {Hardware, Software, ...} - that would mean a Types table in MS SQL with id, Type):

Types: Id, Type
Attribute: Id, Title, TypeId
Project_Attributes: Project_Id, AttributeId (Bridge table for many-to-many)
Projects: Id, Title, ...

Actually a picture worth a thousand words, even this code written in a short time (so needs revisions after some thought) would give more idea. This is code first model, so you could run and let it create the tables for you:

```
string defaultConString = 
@"server=.\SQLExpress;Database=SampleDb;Trusted_Connection=yes;";

void Main()
{
    CreateData();
    // check db state
    ListData();
    // Done with sample database. Delete.
    // new SampleContext(defaultConString).Database.Delete();
}

private void CreateData()
{
    var db = new SampleContext(defaultConString);
    if (db.Database.CreateIfNotExists())
    {

        // Create some types
        var tHW = new Type { Name = "Hardware" };
        var tSW = new Type { Name = "Software" };
        var tFW = new Type { Name = "Firmware" };
        db.Types.AddRange(new Type[] {tHW,tSW,tFW});
        db.SaveChanges();

        // create some Attributes using types above
        var a1 = new Attribute
        {
            Name = "Macbook Pro",
            Type = tHW,
            AttrProperties = new List<AttrProperty> {
                new AttrProperty{ Description=@"15"" retina" },
                new AttrProperty{ Description=@"i9-8950HK" },
                new AttrProperty{ Description=@"32Gb DDR4 RAM" },
                new AttrProperty{ Description=@"512Gb SSD" },
                new AttrProperty{ Description=@"AMD Radeon Pro 555" },
                new AttrProperty{ Description=@"OSX Mojave 10.14" },
                }
        };
        var a2 = new Attribute
        {
            Name = "iMac",
            Type = tHW,
            AttrProperties = new List<AttrProperty> {
                new AttrProperty{ Description=@"27"" retina 5K" },
                new AttrProperty{ Description=@"i5 3.4Ghz" },
                new AttrProperty{ Description=@"40Gb DDR4 RAM" },
                new AttrProperty{ Description=@"1Tb Fusion" },
                new AttrProperty{ Description=@"AMD Radeon Pro 570" },
                new AttrProperty{ Description=@"OSX Mojave 10.14" },
                }
        };
        var a3 = new Attribute
        {
            Name = "PC",
            Type = tHW,
            AttrProperties = new List<AttrProperty> {
                new AttrProperty{ Description=@"AMD Ryzen Threadripper 1950x" },
                new AttrProperty{ Description=@"64Gb RAM" },
                new AttrProperty{ Description=@"1 Tb 7400 RPM" },
                new AttrProperty{ Description=@"512Gb M2 mSATA" },
                new AttrProperty{ Description=@"AMD Radeon Pro 570" },
                new AttrProperty{ Description=@"Linux-Debian 9.5" },
                }
        };

        var a4 = new Attribute
        {
            Name = "Database",
            Type = tSW,
            AttrProperties = new List<AttrProperty> {
                new AttrProperty{ Description=@"postgreSQL" },
                new AttrProperty{ Description=@"11 (beta)" },
                }
        };

        var a5 = new Attribute
        {
            Name = "SomeROM",
            Type = tFW,
            AttrProperties = new List<AttrProperty> {
                new AttrProperty{ Description=@"SomeROM update" },
                new AttrProperty{ Description=@"Some version" },
                }
        };

        db.Attributes.AddRange(new Attribute[] {a1,a2,a3,a4,a5});

        // Some projects using those

        var p1 = new Project
        {
            Name = "P1",
            StartDate = new DateTime(2018, 1, 1),
            Attributes = new List<Attribute>() { a1, a2, a4 }
        };
        var p2 = new Project
        {
            Name = "P2",
            StartDate = new DateTime(2018, 1, 1),
            Attributes = new List<Attribute>() { a1, a3, a5 }
        };
        var p3 = new Project
        {
            Name = "P3",
            StartDate = new DateTime(2018, 1, 1),
            Attributes = new List<Attribute>() { a2, a3, a4, a5 }
        };

        db.Projects.AddRange(new Project[] { p1,p2,p3 });
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
}

private void ListData()
{
    var db = new SampleContext(defaultConString);
//  db.Database.Log =Console.Write;
    foreach (var p in db.Projects.Include("Attributes").ToList())
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Project {p.Name}, started on {p.StartDate}. Has Attributes:");
        foreach (var a in p.Attributes)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"\t{a.Name} [{a.Type.Name}] ({string.Join(",",a.AttrProperties.Select(ap => ap.Description))})");
        }
    }
}

public class Type
{
    public int TypeId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual List<Attribute> Attributes { get; set; }
    public Type()
    {
        Attributes = new List<Attribute>();
    }
}

public class Attribute
{
    public int AttributeId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int TypeId { get; set; }
    public virtual Type Type { get; set; }
    public virtual List<Project> Projects { get; set; }
    public virtual List<AttrProperty> AttrProperties { get; set; }
    public Attribute()
    {
        Projects = new List<Project>();
    }
}

public class AttrProperty
{ 
    public int AttrPropertyId { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public virtual Attribute Attribute {get;set;}
}

public class Project
{
    public int ProjectId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
    public virtual List<Attribute> Attributes {get;set;}

    public Project()
    {
        Attributes = new List<Attribute>();
    }
}


public class SampleContext : DbContext
{
    public SampleContext(string connectionString) : base(connectionString) { }
    public DbSet<Type> Types { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Attribute> Attributes { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Project> Projects { get; set; }
}
```

And if that is not a multiuser big project, then have a look at LiteDB. That might be just what you are looking for and could learn in hours if not in minutes.